# install pygobject3 for python3 in windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygobject

i need to write a python3 program for windows and i want to use gtk+3 for GUI
in GNU/Linux i use python3 and pygobject3 and now i cant find any binary version of pygobject3 for windows x86 or x86_64 !!!
only i find last windows version is 2.28 !!! in this link http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygobject/

where i can find pygobject3 for windows and how to install and use that

thanks for all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone made a win32 binary for pygobject3.03 [here](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.ca/2012/01/pygobject-303-mingw.html) (download link on page).

Also from a blog comment [here](http://www.piware.de/2012/06/pygobject-3-3-3-released/), it looks like the current maintainers aren't interested (or have time) to port to windows.